# When load website via iframe, which IP address will be recognized in the website?

Tags: php, iframe

So there are 2 websites A and B.

A has a page with iframe which loads B.
And B has the back-end code to detect visitor's IP address like following:

```
// Function to get the user IP address
function getUserIP() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

If a user visits the iframe page in A, which IP address will be fetched?

Will it be client's IP address,

or

site A 's IP address?

Comment: That could be easily tested by yourself! The `iframe` is not loaded by the server, it is an instruction for the client to loaded a site in this area, so it is the client ip.

Comment: well, my main purpose is to get the answer as well as the reason why. I can do testing, but then I need to have 2 hosting info... :-( a little hard to do.

Comment: There wouldn't have been the need to use two hostings. One would be sufficent because you could have loaded another page one the same domain. Either you would have seen the ip of the server or the one if the client. Asking for the reason why this is the case or if this will always be the case is clealy differen und would fit more into a question here then just the question if it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iframe element represents a [nested browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context). The iframe source is requested by the user browser. So if you check for IP address you will get the client IP.

Comment: thanks for giving me an idea of nested browsing contect

Comment: @raidenace is there any way to pick A website A's IP while using the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will still get the client's IP address?
Because iframe will send the almost same header I guess.

The client IP address will be sent, too.